# nspasteboard readObjectsForClasses blows up

Tags: nspasteboard

I am trying to implement a simple drag and drop operation in a tableView. However, when I try to retrieve the data from the pasteboard using readObjectsForClasses, I get a runtime exception saying

"[__NSCFConstantString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance  "

This is my acceptDrop method where the problem occurs. Can someone please help point out what I am doing wrong.

```
  (BOOL) tableView: (NSTableView *) view
    acceptDrop: (id ) info
           row: (NSInteger) row
 dropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation) op
   {    

   NSArray *pBoardClasses = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSStringPboardType class], [NSDragPboard class], nil]];
   NSPasteboard *board =[info draggingPasteboard];

   if(![board canReadObjectForClasses:pBoardClasses options:nil])
   {
    NSLog(@"No acceptable data format in pasteboard. Cannot perform this operation!");
    return NO;
   }

   NSArray * dFromPboard = [board readObjectsForClasses:pBoardClasses options:nil];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**use `[NSString class]` instead of `[NSStringPboardType class]`**

also: `[NSDragPboard class]` looks like it's not right. Remove this and test if it works with `[NSString class]` only.

```
NSArray *stringObjects = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:@[ [NSString class], [NSAttributedString class] ] options:@{}];
    if(stringObjects.count > 0) {
        NSString *myStr = stringObjects[0];
        //…
    }
//…
```